# Reduce width of BackBarButtonItem - Navigation Bar Title not centered

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar, backbarbuttonitem

My navigation bar title is not centered because my BackBarButtonItem is too large.

I have tried to include this solution :

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"NewTitle" 
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                    target:nil 
                                    action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
```

or this one:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.width=40;
```

in both ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear but it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BackBarButtonItem was too big because of the text inside.

I have just deleted the text inside with this line of code :

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
```

or this one:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"";
```

in ViewDidLoad method.